Intellij dosen't understand Typescript on React project?
I'm trying to learn React (Vite) with typescript. But I can't get Intellij to work with Typescript. All tsx-files is red, as Intellij does not recognize the language, if I hover it says "Unexpected tokens". I can still start and run the project. The code works without problems in VCS and even if I run Angular with Typescript it works in Intellij. React with Javascript also works fine!
React uses ESLint, i have tried to configure ESLint after som guides but no difference. I will think that if I create the project in Intellij the configuration should be correct.
I have created a React template with both Intellij and in the terminal without any sucess.
I have the Javascript/Typescript plugin in Intellij.
.eslintrc.cjs
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
  ],
  settings: {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"],
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
      }
    }
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.cjs'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['react-refresh'],
  rules: {
    'react-refresh/only-export-components': [
      'warn',
      { allowConstantExport: true },
    ],
  },
}

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?
Thanks!
